# Can nodejs zip a file in stream?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, stream, zip

I want to export data from Mongo uses NodeJS
My step:
1: get data from mongo
2: convert to csv format
3: convert to *.zip file
4: response as download a zip file

I tried with below code, but the file downloaded is a file without extension name, when I open, it seems as a .txt file, I expect it's a zip or gz file.

It's better if I can create 2 streams from 2 collections, convert to 2 csv files and zip it to 1 zip file

```
const { MongoClient } = require('mongodb');
const zlib = require('zlib');
const express = require('express');
const fastCSV = require('fast-csv');

const app = express();

app.get('/', async (req, res) => {
  res.set("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=test.gz");
  const url = process.env.MONGODB_URI;
  const client = new MongoClient(url);
  const dbName = 'db';
  await client.connect();
  const db = client.db(dbName);
  const collection = db.collection('collectionName');
  const stream = await collection.find({ name: 'asd' })
    .stream();

  const csvStream = fastCSV.format({ headers: true }).transform((entry) => {
    return {
      _id: entry._id,
      name: entry.name,
    };
  });

  const gzip = zlib.createGzip();
  stream.pipe(csvStream).pipe(gzip).pipe(res).on('close', () => console.log('Done'));
});
app.listen(3000, () => console.log('listen on 3000'))
```